# If output here is "Not-Equal" then why using double instead of float not give the same output?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

```
  `float x = 0.1;
      if (x == 0.1)
        printf("Equal");
      else
        printf("Not-Equal");`
```

As float chops some bits from the binary representation so does double. Though double 0.1 is having more precision than float but is still not exactly equal and less than 0.1. So, if output for float 0.1 is Not-Equal then output for double 0.1 must be Not-Equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal like 0.1 is a double.

When the compiler processes 'float x = 0.1' it finds the nearest double to 0.1 and then converts it to a float, and assigns that to x.

When the compiler processes 'if ( x == 0.1)' it finds the nearest double to 0.1 and then notices you are comparing a float with a double, so it converts x to a double and compares the doubles.

It is as if you had written

```
double lit = 0.1;
float x = (float)lit;
if ( ((double)x) == lit)
...
```

So the question is: is (double)(float)lit the same as lit? And the answer, in this case, is no.

If you had used 0.1f instead of 0.1 there would be no conversions to doubles, as 0.1f is a float.

Comment: Again then, as you said "it finds the nearest double to 0.1 and then notices you are comparing a float with a double, so it converts x to a double"..How does it notices and consider x as double before even converting it?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In 'if ( x == 0.1)' x is a variable of type float; 0.1 is a literal of type double.